# C# How to get list of users in all roles in RBAC defined in a subscription using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

How to get a list of users in all roles in RBAC defined in a subscription.

```
var authorityUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}";          
var scopes = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(appId, clientSecret, tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
var authenticated1 = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure.Configure().Authenticate(credentials);
IRoleDefinition Rdef = authenticated1.RoleDefinitions.GetByScopeAndRoleName("/", "Owner");
```

Good so far. The inner Rdef give me the role name, ID, and Name and now I am trying to list all users in that subscription scope for that role.

```
var roleassignement1 = authenticated1.RoleAssignments.ListByScopeAsync("/");// GetById("*****")// .GetByScopeAsync("subscriptions/322dac8a-416c-4de6-977c-e6b21344651c", "Owner");
```

What is the scope here, I added the subscription/subid as scope. What I am trying to do is list all RBAC on the subscription.
What am I doing wrong? Any pointer is appreciated.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the code from:

```
var roleassignement1 = authenticated1.RoleAssignments.ListByScopeAsync("/");
```

to

```
var roleassignement1 = await authenticated1.RoleAssignments.ListByScopeAsync("subscriptions/322dac8a-416c-4de6-977c-e6b21344651c");
```

, and then it can work.